# Unicode in Python - parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, unicode

I've written this little code to take JSON files and import their contents into a consul key-value store - I was quite pleased that the recursion works exactly as I expect, however less pleased when the source .json files contained non-ASCII:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import json

filename = str(sys.argv[1])
fh = open(filename)

def printDict (d, path):
  for key in d:
    if isinstance(d[key], dict):
      printDict(d[key], path + str(key) + "/")
    else:
      print 'curl -X PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/' + filename + path + key + ' -d "' + str(d[key]) + '"'
  return

j = json.load(fh)
printDict(j, "/")
```

A sample failing JSON file on disk:

```
{
    "FacetConfig" : {
        "facet:price-lf-p" : {
             "prefixParts" : "£"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code as-is, I'm getting a nasty exception because that nice simple str() can't convert the UK currency pound sign to 7-bit ASCII:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

How can I solve this without making too much of a dog's dinner of code that started out small and elegant? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `str()`, *encode* the unicode value explicitly. Since you are using your value as a URL element, you'll have to encode to your key UTF-8, then URL-quote that; the value just needs encoding to UTF-8.

```
import urllib

print ('curl -X PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/' + filename + path +
       urllib.quote(key.encode('utf8')) + ' -d "' + 
       unicode(d[key]).encode('utf8') + '"')
```

You could use string formatting here to make that a little more readable:

```
print 'curl -X PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/{}{}{} -d "{}"'.format(
    filename, path, urllib.quote(key.encode('utf8')), 
    unicode(d[key]).encode('utf8'))
```

The `unicode()` call is redundant if `d[key]` is always a string value, but if you also have numbers, booleans or `None` values this will make sure the code continues to work.

The server may expect a Content-Type header; if you do send one, perhaps consider adding a `charset=utf8` parameter to the header. It looks like Consul treats the data as opaque, however.

Comment: Hm, it's the d[key] which holds the magic £ sign, however I get a more dramatic error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlquote'

Comment: @gdhgdh: right, typo on my part. You still want to encode your URL properly.

Comment: I took a moment to actually read the error and noticed it was another section of the code, hence I removed the follow-up question. Thank you for replying all the same! :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `str` from `str(d[key])`. That is,

```
print ('curl -X PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/' + filename + 
       path + key + ' -d "' + str(d[key]) + '"')
```

becomes:

```
print ('curl -X PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/' + filename + 
       path + key + ' -d "' + d[key] + '"')
```

The problem here is that the `str` type in Python 2 is basically limited to ASCII characters. `type(d[key])` is `unicode`, so you can't convert it to `str`... but that's fine, we can print it anyways.

Comment: Fair enough I gave an incomplete source; the real files are hundreds of lines and contain bools and integers which str() also provides a great representation of.  Hence, just removing the str() doesn't help (I already tried it ;)

Comment: @gdhgdh: then use `unicode()` rather than `str()` and encode.

Comment: The simple use of unicode() solved it - didn't realise that was even a thing. Awesome, thanks. Now how do I upvote the answer that wasn't actually the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve this without making too much of a dog's dinner of code
>   that started out small and elegant?

Unfortunately, there a several additional steps necessary to prevent decoding/encoding errors.  python 2.x has lots of places where it does *implicit* encoding/decoding, i.e behind your back and without your permission.  When python does an implicit encoding/decoding it uses the ascii codec, which will result in an encoding/decoding error if a utf-8(or any other non-ascii) character is present.  As a result, you have to find all the places where python does implicit encodings/decodings and replace them with explicit encodings/decodings--if you want your program to handle non-ascii characters in those places.

At the very least, any input from an external source should be decoded into a unicode string before proceeding, which means you have to know the input's encoding.  But then if you combine unicode strings with regular strings, you can get encoding/decoding errors, for instance:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-   #Allows utf-8 characters in your source code
unicode_str = '€'.decode('utf-8')
my_str = '{0}{1}'.format('This is the Euro sign: ', unicode_str) 

--output:--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 3, in <module>
    my_str = '{0}{1}'.format('hello', unicode_str) 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Therefore all your strings probably should be decoded into unicode strings. Then when you want to output the strings, you need to encode the unicode strings.

```
import sys
import json
import codecs
import urllib

def printDict(d, path, filename):
    for key, val in d.items():  #key is a unicode string, val is a unicode string or dict
        if isinstance(val, dict): 
            printDict(
                val,
                u'{0}{1}/'.format(path, key),  #format() specifiers require 0,1 for python 2.6
                filename
            )
        else:
            key_str = key.encode('utf-8')
            val_str = val.encode('utf-8')

            url = '{0}{1}{2} -d "{3}"'.format(
                filename, 
                path, 
                key_str, 
                val_str
            )
            print url
            url_escaped = urllib.quote(url)
            print url_escaped

            curl_cmd = 'curl -X PUT'            
            base_url = 'http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/'
            print "{0} {1}{2}".format(curl_cmd, base_url, url_escaped)


filename = sys.argv[1].decode('utf-8')
file_encoding = 'utf-8'
fh = codecs.open(filename, encoding=file_encoding)
my_json = json.load(fh)
fh.close()

print my_json

path = "/"
printDict(my_json, path.decode('utf-8'), filename)  #Can the path have  non-ascii characters in it?

--output:--
{u'FacetConfig': {u'facet:price-lf-p': {u'prefixParts': u'\xa3'}}}
data.txt/FacetConfig/facet:price-lf-p/prefixParts -d "£"
data.txt/FacetConfig/facet%3Aprice-lf-p/prefixParts%20-d%20%22%C2%A3%22
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/data.txt/FacetConfig/facet%3Aprice-lf-p/prefixParts%20-d%20%22%C2%A3%22
```

Comment: Don't use `codecs.open()`; `json.load()` expects to load bytes, in Python 2.

Comment: *Encodings that are not ASCII based (such as UCS-2) are not allowed, and should be wrapped with codecs.getreader(encoding)(fp), or simply decoded to a unicode object and passed to loads().* https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json

Comment: Sorry, misread that. Personally, I'd avoid `codecs.getreader()` as there are plenty of issues with the `codecs` I/O implementation. Use `io.open()` instead. But clearly, the issue the OP has are not with the input file.

Comment: Clearly, input and output are related, and they have to operate in sync with each other.  So, you should establish a baseline by decoding input into unicode strings, e.g. by specifying a file's encoding when you open it, then for output you encode() the unicode strings.  See my answer for an example of how to do that.